# Error installing Python 3.3.2 64-bit in Windows 7

Tags: 64-bit, python, windows-installer

Today I tried installing Python 3.3.2 64-bit on my Toshiba Satellite L755 laptop, and I get the error from the image below, and I don't know how to get around it.  I tried restarting Windows in safe mode and that gave me an error stating basically that the Windows Installer doesn't work (.MSI files) in Safe Mode.

**Files in Use**
Some files that need to be updated are currently in use.

... 
Programs listed were:
AMD FUEL Service (Process ID: 1352)
Catalyst Control Center: Host application (Process ID: 1984)

[image: Python 3.3.2 installation error image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried closing those applications via task manager and retrying to install Python like it says?

Comment: I haven't.  I didn't know if that would cause any weird problems since those are programs I didn't run on my own (i.e. they're run on startup).  I did find the solution though.

Comment: Hi James! Your question is perfectly on topic here too, so we'll leave it on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to solve this.  I hope this helps out anyone with this problem in the future.

**Start** > **Run** > **msconfig.exe**

**Services** tab > uncheck **AMD Fuel Service**
**Startup** tab > uncheck **Catalyst Control Center**

Click **Apply**, **Ok**, **Restart**

Choose to **Reboot Now**

Then if you want to enable those programs again, after installing Python, run msconfig.exe again, and recheck the boxes, Apply, Ok, Restart

(i.e. Rinse, Lather, Repeat)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing 32-bit version instead. It will be fine and will add support to some extra modules which 64-bit version does not endorse. I am using a 32-bit python on a 64-bit windows machine and it is doing its job pretty well.

Comment: That's a great idea.  If I hadn't just found the workaround I definitely would have done that.  I may end up doing it someday anyway if I find some modules I can't live without.